# How to change ownership of extracted attachments (postfix, procmail, uudeview)?

Tags: attachment, postfix-mta, procmail

I have managed to extract all attachments from emails being delivered to a certain email to a public folder on my linux server (using postfix->procmail->uudeview). Unfortunately the files themselves are saved with the permissions restricted to the system user that the files were sent to (called 'scans').

How can I build a "chmod 777 /path/to/folder/*.pdf" into my setup so that the files (which are coming from my scanner) are available to anyone?

Is there a better way to do this?

Regards
Frank

Answer (score 2):

Whatever it is that you are doing, `chmod 777` is so misdirected as to lose your computer driver's license.  It is a **serious security problem** to make files world-writable and executable.

You are probably looking for Procmail's `UMASK` variable.  If permissions are too tight, set a more relaxed `UMASK` before delivering.  Example:

```
:0
* some conditions
{
    UMASK=003
    :0
    | uudeview --whatever
}
```

The `umask` system call can only strip permissions, not add them.  Typically, a C program tries to create a data file using mode `0666` and then the `umask` is applied, often yielding something like `0644` (meaning the effective `umask` was something like `0022` or `0033`). On Linux, the [directory's permissions also somewhat influence the permissions](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Directory-Setuid-and-Setgid.html) of newly created files.  But we are venturing outside of Procmail here.  Perhaps you can achieve the end result you require by combining the `UMASK` facility of Procmail with directory permissions.

If the "attachments" you are extracting are not MIME attachments but actual `uuencode`,  note also that the encoding [specifies permissions for every encoded file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding). If the `begin` line says `644` then you might have to change that.  Procmail to the rescue again!

```
:0
* some conditions
{
    UMASK=003
    | sed 's/^begin [0-7][0-7][0-7][0-7]* /begin 664 /' | uudeview --whatever
}
```

In the end, if even this doesn't help, it may come down to modifying `uudeview`, perhaps by tweaking its source, or by creating a wrapper which fixes up permissions after writing.

Comment: I suspected that the 777 wouldn't go down well ;)

Comment: The UMASK does what I am after but only "half way". I have tried UMASK=001, UMASK=003, UMASK=010 and UMASK=100, but all just provide rw-r--r-- access to the files.

My .procmailrc is:

:0
*^content-Type:
{
UMASK=001
:0fw
| uudeview -p /home/storage/scans -
}

Comment: Updated somewhat.  Incidentally, your condition on the presence of the `Content-Type:` header is kind of weird. If it works for you, good; but basically all MIME messages have that.